# Apache configured to ridirect urls to Joomla but then How can I still access Moodle?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla, moodle

I configured the .htaccess file like this:

### Mod_rewrite in use.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/pathtopublichtml/joomla/  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pathtopublichtml/joomla/$1 [L]
```

But then when I try to get to `/domain.com/moodle` Apache takes me to Joomla. How Can I access both ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `RewriteCond` to exclude any `REQUEST_URI` that starts with 'moodle'

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/pathtopublichtml/joomla/
# Make sure the redirect is not done for moodle
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^moodle
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pathtopublichtml/joomla/$1 [L]
```